# How to use isolated development database in shared Visual Studio solution

Tags: version-control, sql-server-2008-r2, database-project

I'm leading a small software development team (4 people), and have just broken ground on a source-controlled SQL Server 2008 database project, with isolated development databases for each developer. I'm still implementing this one step at a time, but I'm envisioning each developer having their own database, with a naming scheme something like `<ProjectName>_DEVELOPMENT_<TFSUserName>`. This was all recommended per the MSDN articles I've been reading, but someone let me know if that sounds way off.

Anyway, we have a shared application solution that we've been developing for some time. In the past, we had no database version control, and just modified our database directly from SQL Server Management Studio when new reference data needed to be populated, or when we were testing functionality -- one change immediately affected everyone else. So with this new change, I'm wondering what the best way would be to have each person connect to their isolated development databases from the application solution. Prior to isolated databases, our connection to the database was specified in our application's web.config as a connection string. If we're each going to have our own database, the only way I can see it working is for each developer to set their connection string in their local solution to point to their personal database. But changing the web.config will check out that file in the solution, so developers will always have to specifically uncheck that file when checking in application changes to the baseline. Is there a less clunky way for each developer to use their isolated database when doing application testing?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you *not* make the database names username-specific. Instead make the database the same name for each developer and always reference it via localhost (`localhost\<ProjectName>_DEVELOPMENT`). Then the same connection string will work for every developer.

MSDN's suggestion to use username-specific databases is better for a shared development environment. It's definitely not ideal for a localized environment.